# Saving faces openCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection

I have a code to crop faces and I'm trying to to save cropped images. My code saves only one image. Can you please help me expand functionality so program saves all the faces into separate files

```
import cv2
import os


def facecrop(image):
    facedata = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(facedata)

    img = cv2.imread('class.jpg')

    minisize = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
    miniframe = cv2.resize(img, minisize)

    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(miniframe)

    for f in faces:
        x, y, w, h = [v for v in f]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255))

        sub_face = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(image)
        cv2.imwrite(fname + "_cropped_" + ext, sub_face)

    return
```

facecrop("1.jpg")

Comment: Is there only one face per image? if no then your code saves only one face per image, you'd have to make some changes in their names for that.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have a counter and add it in your file name. What happening is, you are overwriting the images with the same filename. Hence you are getting only one image. Below is the code snippet

```
import cv2
import os


def facecrop(image):
    facedata = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(facedata)

    img = cv2.imread('class.jpg')

    minisize = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
    miniframe = cv2.resize(img, minisize)

    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(miniframe)
    counter = 1

    for f in faces:
        x, y, w, h = [v for v in f]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255))

        sub_face = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(image)
        cv2.imwrite(fname + "_cropped_" + str(counter) + ext, sub_face)
        counter = counter + 1

    return
```

Hope it helps!